# rails habtm association implementation giving issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models, meetings and attendees which share a habtm relationship. I also have a User model to which a meeting can belong (as a meeting organizer).

```
class Meeting < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :organizer, :class_name => User, :foreign_key => "organizer_id"
  has_and_belongs_to_many :attendees, :class_name => User, :association_foreign_key => "attendee_id"
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :meetings, :class_name => Meeting, :association_foreign_key => "meeting_id"
end
```

and then I have the relationship table..

```
create_table "attendees_meetings", :id => false, :force => true do |t|
  t.integer "attendee_id"
  t.integer "meeting_id"
end
```

When I create a new meeting, and then reference the attendees as meeting.attendees, I get an error. Also the same thing with organizer, meeting.organizer throws an error. Have I not setup the relationships properly?

```
m = Meeting.create(:subject => "Test", :location => "Neverland", :body => "A test", :organizer_id => 8)
m.organizer
NoMethodError: undefined method `match' for #<Class:0x00000103d8cf08>
```

The same with attendees (though I have not defined any at the moment but shouldn't be throwing an error)

```
1.9.2-p318 :014 > m.attendees
(Object doesn't support #inspect)
=>
```

Comment: If you comment out the `:attendees` association do you still have trouble creating a meeting?  Also, `:class_name` is supposed to hold a string (`"User"`) not an actual class (`User`).

Answer (score 0):

The `class_name` option on the `has_and_belongs_to_many` should be a string which is the name of the class. You have passed the class object itself. So, for example,

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :attendees, 
    :class_name => "User", 
    :association_foreign_key => "attendee_id"
```

I think you may also need to add a `:foreign_key => 'attendee_id'` on the `has_and_belongs_to_many` declaration in your `User` model and can remove the `:association_foreign_key` option because it is the default. Actually you can probably lose the `:class_name` option too as that is also the default. So:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :meetings, 
    :foreign_key => "attendee_id"
```

Comment: I have some progress. I made the change with changing the class names with the string and that seemed to fix the issue of meeting.organizer being defined. I also noticed that my association table needed to be meetings_users, and not attendees_meetings. I'm still having an issue addressing meeting.attendees where it says: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: meetings_users.user_id: SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "meetings_users" ON "users"."id" = "meetings_users"."user_id" WHERE "meetings_users"."attendee_id" = 26

Comment: Are the fields in my association table supposed to be meeting_id and attendee_id, or meeting_id and user_id?

Comment: If the table is meetings_users then I think it should be meeting_id and user_id. However, you can use attendees_meetings if you specify `:join_table => 'attendees_meetings'`. Sorry, I missed that in your question.